# ReactJS - How to get a reference to the current element/component for further rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to pass as a variable, the JSX.Element of the current component being displayed.

In this example on CodeSandbox, a main menu navigates to an activity screen after a button click.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-moon-kbznm?file=/src/App.tsx

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        Header - hello I remain unchanged
        <div id="screen-container">
            <Menu />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

First, I use a div with an id as a main container after my header. Later, I'll use a navigateToElement() function to place JSX.Element in that container:

```
function navigateToElement(screen: JSX.Element) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    screen,
    document.getElementById("screen-container")
  );
}
```

The component appearing first inside the container div is `<Menu/>`:

```
export function Menu() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I am the menu</h1>
      <button onClick={() => {
         navigateToElement(<Activity/>);
      }}>Start activity</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It displays one button that calls the navigateToElement() function to replace the `<Menu/>` by the `<Activity/>` component.
The `<Activity/>` component contains a button to go back to the menu.

```
export function Activity() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Activity screen</h1>
      <button onClick={() => {
         navigateToElement(<Menu/>);
      }}>Back to menu</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It works fine, but in the `<Activity/>` component, I've hardcoded to go back to `<Menu/>`.
Would it be possible instead to go back to "where I come from"?

In that scenario:

- 1. The menu displays.
- 2a. The user clicks the button on the menu.
- 2b. The menu's button handler gets a reference to itself and pass it to
  the Action component.

Something like:

```
var refToMenu = ..... reference to myself
navigateToElement(<Activity/>);
```

- 3. The activity component displays
- 4a. The user click the "back to menu" button
- 4b. The activity component navigates to the menu referred through the variable.

`navigateToElement(refToMenu);`

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?
Many thanks.
John.

Comment: Yes, you should try using the React Router library for navigation https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview. Then you can use the useNavigate hook to go back.